# openmpi: MPI_recv hangs for specific number of processes

Tags: mpi, openmpi, lustre

I am running a HPC benchmark (IOR - http://sourceforge.net/projects/ior-sio/) on lustre. I compiled the source of IOR and running it with openmpi 1.5.3.

The problem is that it hangs when the number of processes (`-np`) is less than 6, which is odd. Removing all other things I do with around, the actual command that I run comes down to this:

```
/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpirun --machinefile mpi_hosts --bynode -np 16 /path/to/IOR -F -u -t 1m -b 16g -i 1 -o /my/file/system/out_file
```

Attaching the process to GDB shows that process hangs at MPI_recv:

```
#0  0x00007f3ac49e95fe in mlx4_poll_cq () from /usr/lib64/libmlx4-m-rdmav2.so
#1  0x00007f3ac6ce0918 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so
#2  0x000000385a6f0d5a in opal_progress () from /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1
#3  0x00007f3ac7511e05 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so
#4  0x000000385a666cac in PMPI_Recv () from /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1
#5  0x0000000000404bd7 in CountTasksPerNode (numTasks=16, comm=0x628a80) at IOR.c:526
#6  0x0000000000407d53 in SetupTests (argc=11, argv=0x7fffe61fa2a8) at IOR.c:1402
#7  0x0000000000402e96 in main (argc=11, argv=0x7fffe61fa2a8) at IOR.c:134
```

This problem happens only when `-np` is 2/3/4/5. It works for 1/6/7/8/16 etc.

I can't reproduce this problem if I use simple commands such as `date` or `ls`. So I am not sure if this is a problem with my environment or IOR binary that I compiled (very unlikely because the same happens with an older/stable IOR binary too).

Also the precise behaviour is observed when using openmpi1.4.3 instead of openmpi1.5.3.

I have also tried by using various number of hosts (`--machinefile` argument) and same behaviour is observed for the the above mentioned `-np` values.
The source line it hangs is this:

```
MPI_Recv(hostname, MAX_STR, MPI_CHAR, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, comm, &status);
```

Basically I am looking for clues as to why `MPI_recv()` might hang when `-np` is 2/3/4/5. Please let me know if other information is needed. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be an InfiniBand-related problem. `mlx4_poll_cq` is called to poll the completion queue of the IB HCA and since it hangs in a receive operaiton, it means that the other side (e.g. another rank) is not completing the send. Check your InfiniBand equipment and kernel parameters. Or, even better, post your question to the [Open MPI Users](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/ompi.php) mailing list.

Comment: I suspected that too. I checked the HCAs locally and they seemed OK. I am not an IB expert and I'll ask some help from my h/w engineers. I'll give another try on Monday and take it from there. Thanks for your time and helpful suggestions :)

Comment: IOR has been around a long long time.  I doubt the fault lies with IOR, though IOR or any file system benchmark are quite good at uncovering hardware faults.   You might find  IOR from github has a bit better reporting: https://github.com/chaos/ior

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to mind: `MPI_Recv` is a blocking receive, and will wait until a matching `MPI_Send` is called. However, if what you are sending is small enough (i.e., it fits in the buffer that MPI sets aside for such tasks), then the function will actually not wait, and instead carry on through the code. For higher core counts, you may be sending less with each `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv` command, so the data fits in the buffer and everything continues on its way. With lower core counts, there is too much data to fit in the buffer and `MPI_Recv` hangs as you have not called an appropriate `MPI_Send` for the information to get there. A quick and easy way to test this hypothesis: decrease the problem size substantially; does it still hang at all of those core counts? If not, then that is further evidence for my hypothesis and you will need to provide more code so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: hmmm...but if doesn't hang with 1 process, which contradicts with this suggestion. It's true that the data I send is quite large (order of GBs). I'll try with various sizes, including very small values. Source can be seen in the link in question. It's too much of code, really and I am not familiar with it completely to produce a SO-fit-problem-reproducible code. Thanks.

Comment: @BlueMoon: It doesn't hang with 1 process because you shouldn't be sending anything at all when you only have 1 processor (nothing to send to), so it should return regardless of problem size.

Comment: Right. I'll try with various sizes with multiple processes then.